# Make first section rows cell already expanded in Expandable table view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my App I implemented Expandable tableview. It's worked perfectly but now I want to change the first section was already expandable mode but I unable to do that.

Here I have implemented my own native code for creating expandable tableview not using any third party libraries.

Here I post my Full code for Expandable TableView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewSecond: UITableView!
var hidden = [true]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableViewSecond.delegate = self
    tableViewSecond.dataSource = self
    InspectionArray = [["inspection_name":"AVM Inspection"], ["inspection_name":"Simple Inspection"], ["inspection_name":"BVM Inspection"]]
    InspectionSectionArray = [["inspection_Session":"Current Inspection"], ["inspection_Session":"Past Inspection"], ["inspection_Session":"Future Inspection"]]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    for _ in 0..<InspectionSectionArray.count {
        hidden.append(true)
    }
    return InspectionSectionArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if hidden[section] {
        return 0
    } else {
        return InspectionArray.count
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
    headerView.tag = section
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = (InspectionSectionArray[section] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "inspection_Session") as? String
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 45, y: 5, width: 150, height: 35)
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    headerView.addSubview(label)
    label.tag = section
    
    let tapForheaderView = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(SecondViewController.tapFunction))
    headerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapForheaderView)
    
    return headerView
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 2
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 45
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? SecondTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "SecondTableViewCell") as? SecondTableViewCell;
    }
    cell!.dataLbl.text = (InspectionArray[indexPath.row] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "inspection_name") as? String
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print(indexPath.row)
    print("\(indexPath.section)","\(indexPath.row)")
}

func tapFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let section = sender.view!.tag
    let indexPaths = (0..<InspectionArray.count).map { i in return IndexPath(item: i, section: section)  }
    hidden[section] = !hidden[section]
    tableViewSecond.beginUpdates()
    if hidden[section] {
        tableViewSecond.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    } else {
        tableViewSecond.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }
    tableViewSecond.endUpdates()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only need to change this:

```
// declare hidden as this
var hidden: [Bool] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    InspectionArray = [["inspection_name":"AVM Inspection"], ["inspection_name":"Simple Inspection"], ["inspection_name":"BVM Inspection"]]
    InspectionSectionArray = [["inspection_Session":"Current Inspection"], ["inspection_Session":"Past Inspection"], ["inspection_Session":"Future Inspection"]]

    // initialize hidden array so that the first is false and the rest true
    hidden = Array<Bool>(repeating: true, count: InspectionSectionArray.count)
    hidden[0] = false

    tableViewSecond.delegate = self
    tableViewSecond.dataSource = self
}

// and change numberOfSections to this
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return InspectionSectionArray.count
}
```

Comment: Bro It shows error like , "Instance member 'InspectionSectionArray' cannot be used on type 'SecondViewController'" when declare hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this function

```
func tapFunction(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer?) {

    var section = 0

    if sender != nil {
        section = sender!.view!.tag
    }

    let indexPaths = (0..<InspectionArray.count).map { i in return IndexPath(item: i, section: section)  }
    hidden[section] = !hidden[section]
    tableViewSecond.beginUpdates()
    if hidden[section] {
        tableViewSecond.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    } else {
        tableViewSecond.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }
    tableViewSecond.endUpdates()
}
```

And call `self.tapFunction(sender: nil)` in `viewdidLoad`.